# Lottery number generator and checker with tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Background: So I'm planning an escape room game for my family during the Holidays. One part of the puzzle is that they should find a hidden lottery number in the room that needs to be entered into a computer. When the correct number is entered, they will receive their next clue.

I'm new to making GUIs so I am having some difficulties in how I should go about it. My number one problem currently is that I have not been able to retrieve the information that the user has entered into the input fields, which then should be compared to the correct numbers.

The code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

Lottery = Tk()
Lottery.geometry('800x360')
Lottery.resizable(0, 0)
Lottery.title("Lottery")

def draw_numbers():
   random_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 31), 6)
   random_numbers.sort()
   text.config(text = random_numbers)

##COMPUTER INPUT
var = StringVar()
var.set("Lottery numbers")
frame1 = Frame(Lottery)
frame1.pack(side=TOP)

label = Label(frame1, textvariable=var, font =("Arial", 24), width=20)
label.pack(side=TOP)

##COMPUTER NUMBERS
button = Button(frame1, text = "Draw numbers", width = 25, command = draw_numbers)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1)

text = Label(frame1, text = random.sample(range(1, 31), 6))
text.pack(padx = 0, pady = 1)

##USER INPUT
frame2 = Frame(Lottery)
var = StringVar()
var.set("Choose 6 numbers between 1 - 30.")
frame2 = Frame(Lottery)
frame2.pack(side=TOP)

label = Label(frame1, textvariable=var, font
=("Arial", 24), width=70)
label.pack(side=TOP)

#USER NUMBERS
frame2.pack(side=TOP)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)
txtDisplay = Entry(frame2, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 24), justify='center', width=4)
txtDisplay.pack(side=LEFT)

Lottery.mainloop()
```

Problems:

1. The textfields where the user can input their numbers doesn't show unless you click on the frame.
2. How do I retrieve the information that is entered in the textfields so that I can compare it to the correct numbers?

Alternative: If I'm not able to create the program in a GUI, I guess I will resort to make it a program that can be run in the terminal, for instance:

```
import time
import random

while True:
    random_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 31), 6)
    random_numbers.sort()
    correct_numbers = [1,3,5,13,16]

    print("Choose 6 numbers between 1-30")
    num1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "))
    num3 = int(input("Enter your third number: "))
    num4 = int(input("Enter your fourth number is: "))
    num5 = int(input("Enter your fifth number: "))
    print()
    input("Press enter to draw numbers: ")
    print("…")

    guessed_numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
    guessed_numbers.sort()
    if guessed_numbers == correct_numbers:
            print("Your numbers are: " + str(guessed_numbers))
            print("The drawn numbers are…")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(correct_numbers)
            print("Congratulations, all numbers are correct! Your next clue is..")
            break
    else:
            print("Your numbers are: " + str(guessed_numbers))
            print("The drawn numbers are…")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(random_numbers)
            print("Sorry! Better luck next time..")
```

In my code so far I have used help from the following sources:
https://pretagteam.com/question/cant-get-the-code-to-work-for-this-random-number-generator-in-tkinter
https://github.com/manjurulhoque/python-lottery-number-generator/blob/master/lottery_number_generator.py

Comment: Using `focus_set()` to set focus for input, maybe you need to define how to switch between entries, like TAB key or bind Return key, also when input complete to validate.  Option `validatecommand` of Entry to check each input. Set option `textvariable=variable` where `variable = tk.StringVar()`, to get the content by `variable.get()`, or by `widget.get()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Problem 1 resolved itself somehow and problem 2 was resolved with variable.get(). 

I didn't really understand what those other functions does or how to use them, but I will try to check them out in order to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not prettiest solution, but I got the main functions that I was looking for working. [image: Lottery escape]

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import time

correct_numbers = [1,3,5,13,16,23]
def Lotto_No():
    try:
        inp_num1 = int(txtInput1.get())
        inp_num2 = int(txtInput2.get())
        inp_num3 = int(txtInput3.get())
        inp_num4 = int(txtInput4.get())
        inp_num5 = int(txtInput5.get())
        inp_num6 = int(txtInput6.get())
        inp_numlist = [inp_num1, inp_num2, inp_num3, inp_num4, inp_num5, inp_num6]
        inp_numlist.sort()        
        if inp_numlist == correct_numbers:
            x = correct_numbers[0]
            q = correct_numbers[1]
            w = correct_numbers[2]
            e = correct_numbers[3]
            r = correct_numbers[4]
            t = correct_numbers[5]
            num1.set(x)
            num2.set(q)
            num3.set(w)
            num4.set(e)
            num5.set(r)
            num6.set(t)
            return
        else:
            random_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 41), 6)
            random_numbers.sort()
            
            x = random_numbers[0]
            q = random_numbers[1]
            w = random_numbers[2]
            e = random_numbers[3]
            r = random_numbers[4]
            t = random_numbers[5]
            num1.set(x)
            num2.set(q)
            num3.set(w)
            num4.set(e)
            num5.set(r)
            num6.set(t)
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    
def retrieve_numbers():
    try:
        num1 = int(txtInput1.get())
        num2 = int(txtInput2.get())
        num3 = int(txtInput3.get())
        num4 = int(txtInput4.get())
        num5 = int(txtInput5.get())
        num6 = int(txtInput6.get())
        num7 = int(txtOutput1.get())
        num8 = int(txtOutput2.get())
        num9 = int(txtOutput3.get())
        num10 = int(txtOutput4.get())
        num11 = int(txtOutput5.get())
        num12 = int(txtOutput6.get())
        numlist = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6]
        randlist = [num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12]
        numlist.sort()
        randlist.sort()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def output_message():
    try:
        num1 = int(txtInput1.get())
        num2 = int(txtInput2.get())
        num3 = int(txtInput3.get())
        num4 = int(txtInput4.get())
        num5 = int(txtInput5.get())
        num6 = int(txtInput6.get())
        num7 = int(txtOutput1.get())
        num8 = int(txtOutput2.get())
        num9 = int(txtOutput3.get())
        num10 = int(txtOutput4.get())
        num11 = int(txtOutput5.get())
        num12 = int(txtOutput6.get())
        numlist = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6]
        randlist = [num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12]
        numlist.sort()
        randlist.sort()
        print(numlist)
        print(randlist)
        if correct_numbers == numlist:
            message= "Correct!"
            message_text.set(message)
        elif numlist == randlist:
            message = "Correct!! Amazing, you managed to guess the correct answer. "
            message_text.set(message)
        else: 
            message = ["Incorrect! Try again!","Bad luck! Try again!", "Incorrect!", "Incorrect!", "You are just guessing aren't you?"]
            message_text.set(random.choice(message))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        message = "Check that you have entered all fields correctly"
        message_text.set(message)



Lottery = Tk()
Lottery.geometry('800x460')
Lottery.resizable(0, 0)
frame = Frame(Lottery)
frame.pack()

Lottery.title('Room Escape Lottery machine')

num1 = StringVar()
num2 = StringVar()
num3 = StringVar()
num4 = StringVar()
num5 = StringVar()
num6 = StringVar()
message_text = StringVar()

var = StringVar()
var.set("Choose 6 numbers between 1-40.")
frame1 = Frame(Lottery)
frame1.pack(side=TOP)

label = Label(frame1, textvariable=var, font
=("Arial", 28), width=44)
label.pack(side=TOP)

label2 = Label(frame1, textvariable="", width=24)
label2.pack(side=TOP)
label2 = Label(frame1, textvariable="", width=24)
label2.pack(side=TOP)


frame1.pack(side=TOP)
txtInput1 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput1.pack(side=LEFT)
txtInput2 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput2.pack(side=LEFT)
txtInput3 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput3.pack(side=LEFT)
txtInput4 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput4.pack(side=LEFT)
txtInput5 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput5.pack(side=LEFT)
txtInput6 = Entry(frame1, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtInput6.pack(side=LEFT)

#BUTTON
frame3 = Frame(Lottery)
frame3.pack(side=TOP)
button1 = Button(frame3, padx=8, width=20, pady=8, bd=8, font=("Arial", 26), text="Draw lottery numbers", bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda:[Lotto_No(), retrieve_numbers(), output_message()])
button1.pack(side=TOP)

frame2 = Frame(Lottery)
frame2.pack(side=TOP)
txtOutput1 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num1, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput1.pack(side=LEFT)
txtOutput2 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num2, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput2.pack(side=LEFT)
txtOutput3 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num3, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput3.pack(side=LEFT)
txtOutput4 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num4, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput4.pack(side=LEFT)
txtOutput5 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num5, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput5.pack(side=LEFT)
txtOutput6 = Entry(frame2, textvariable=num6, state = DISABLED, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=("Arial", 30), justify='center', width=4)
txtOutput6.pack(side=LEFT)

frame4 = Frame(Lottery)
frame4.pack(side=BOTTOM)
button2 = Entry(frame4, bd=0, textvariable=message_text, insertwidth=50,state = DISABLED,  font=("Arial", 15), justify='center', width=100)

button2.pack(side=TOP)

Lottery.mainloop()
```